# Backbone JS find the minimum value

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have this json which populates my collection (`TableListCollection`) of models (`TableModel)`

```
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "tableId": 15,
            "size": 8,
            "occupiedSeats": 0,
            "stakes": {
                "smallBlindAmount": 10,
                "bigBlindAmount": 20,
                "minBuyInAmount": 20,
                "maxBuyInAmount": 200
            },
            "gameType": "HOLDEM",
            "gameSpeed": "NORMAL",
            "friends": []
        },
        {
            "tableId": 16,
            "size": 8,
            "occupiedSeats": 0,
            "stakes": {
                "smallBlindAmount": 20,
                "bigBlindAmount": 40,
                "minBuyInAmount": 20,
                "maxBuyInAmount": 200
            },
            "gameType": "HOLDEM",
            "gameSpeed": "NORMAL",
            "friends": []
        },
        {
            "tableId": 17,
            "size": 8,
            "occupiedSeats": 0,
            "stakes": {
                "smallBlindAmount": 40,
                "bigBlindAmount": 60,
                "minBuyInAmount": 20,
                "maxBuyInAmount": 200
            },
            "gameType": "HOLDEM",
            "gameSpeed": "NORMAL",
            "friends": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find the table with the minimum `smallBlindAmount`.

I see that I can use the `_.min()` but I can't figure out what I have to pass as an iterator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either directly on the JSON

```
var json=...
var min = _.min(json.tables,function(item) {
    return item.stakes.smallBlindAmount
});
console.log(min.stakes.smallBlindAmount);
```

or on your collection

```
var json=...
var c=new Backbone.Collection(json.tables);
var m=c.min(function(model) {
    return model.get("stakes").smallBlindAmount
});
console.log(m.get("stakes").smallBlindAmount);
```

In both cases, the iterator is used to extract the values to be compared.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the iterator must contain the logic